# How to pass struct type in arguments?

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, linked-list

How to pass struct type in arguments? I guess it is not possible, still wanted to check if it is feasible.

My requirement is something like this

Below is a macro `list_entry` used in linux kernel

```
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    ((type *)((char *)(ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))
```

I want to rewrite it using function. How do I write?

```
list_entry(void *ptr, ???, ???)
```

Is there a way we can do this?

I am trying to write a wrapper to free a given list. So to use list_entry in my function, my function needs to be passed with type and the member. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fundamentally not possible to write `list_entry`, with its same behavior and signature, as a function. This is because its arguments include a type and a member name, neither of which is a value in C.

On the other hand, you could to some extent abstract out the "code" content of the macro into a function:

```
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    ((type *)f_list_entry(ptr, offsetof(type, member)))

static void *f_list_entry(void *ptr, size_t offset)
{
    return (char *)(ptr)-offset;
}
```

But as you can see, the only actual "code" is a single subtraction.

Since I used the standard `offsetof` macro rather than the kernel's *invocation of undefined behavior* via a poor hack, I also took the liberty of fixing the type-correctness (`size_t` instead of `unsigned long`).